# Help with Time-Seried dataset

Tags: interpolation, data, dataset, time-series

I can't seem to figure out the best way for directly inputting interpolated values into a dataset. I turn to your expertise for guidance.

So, I have a multi-year time-series dataset. Column 1 is time in AbsoluteTime and Column 2 is measurements. The set has data points every 30 minutes. I want to get the interpolated values for every 15 minute mark directly put into my dataset. I have used interpolation on the set, but now I want to create the datapoints (timestamp and measurement) for each midpoint between two datapoints.

Here is a small sample of the data:

```
s1 = {{3534364800, 0}, {3534365700, 0}, {3534366600,12.3}, {3534367500, 53.8}, {3534368400, 100.1}, {3534369300, 141.8}, {3534370200, 131.2}, {3534371100,90.3}, {3534372000, 50.2}, {3534372900, 11.2}, {3534373800, 0}, {3534374700, 0};
```

The time stamp increases by 900 each step. I'd like to get the data at each 450 mark

Here's what I got so far.

```
a = Interpolation[s1];
b = Table[a[3534364800 + 450 i], {i, 0, 22}]
c = Table[# & /@ s1[[1, 1]] + 450 i, {i, 0, 22}]
Transpose[{c, b}]
{{3534364800, 0.}, {3534365250, -0.48125}, {3534365700,0.}, {3534366150, 3.55625}, {3534366600, 12.3}, {3534367050,30.925}, {3534367500, 53.8}, {3534367950, 76.9375}, {3534368400, 100.1}, {3534368850, 124.506}, {3534369300, 141.8}, {3534369750, 141.663}, {3534370200, 131.2}, {3534370650, 112.594}, {3534371100, 90.3}, {3534371550, 70.1313}, {3534372000, 50.2}, {3534372450, 28.8938}, {3534372900, 11.2}, {3534373350, 3.1625}, {3534373800, 0.}, {3534374250, -0.3625}, {3534374700, 0.}}
```

Seems like there is a MUCH better way to go about this.

Any thoughts are much appreciated. Thanks ahead of time for all your help.

Comment: You might want to look at the documentation for `Interpolation`. Define `s = Interpolation[s1];` Then `s[3534364850]` gives the value at that time point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at `TimeSeries` and related. They are a *very* powerful set of tools to use. Using your data, we can build a time series:

```
ts = TimeSeries[s1, ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 3}];
```

You can change the interpolation order to be whatever you want.

Now that we have a `TimeSeries` you can use `TimeSeriesResample` to get what you want:

```
rts = TimeSeriesResample[ts, 450];
```

Now we can visualize the resampled `TimeSeries` versus the original:

```
DateListPlot[{ts, rts}, Joined -> False, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]